# WCF netTcpBinding fails when IIS is running under identity of domain user (SSPI authentication failed)

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

We have a WPF application which connects to WCF services using `netTcpBinding` using `TransportWithMessageCredential` security with `clientCredentialType` set to `Windows` for message and transport security. IIS app pool is running under identity of a domain user.

The above setup works locally just fine (meaning that WCF services and WPF app are running from on same box). When WPF app is on a different box then the communication fails with the following error:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: SOAP
>   security negotiation with
>   'net.tcp://serv01.domain.local:30128/UsersService.svc' for target
>   'net.tcp://serv01.domain.local:30128/UsersService.svc' failed. See
>   inner exception for more details. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Security Support Provider
>   Interface (SSPI) authentication failed. The server may not be running
>   in an account with identity 'host/serv01.domain.local'. If the
>   server is running in a service account (Network Service for example),
>   specify the account's ServicePrincipalName as the identity in the
>   EndpointAddress for the server. If the server is running in a user
>   account, specify the account's UserPrincipalName as the identity in
>   the EndpointAddress for the server.    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.WindowsSspiNegotiation.GetOutgoingBlob(Byte[]
>   incomingBlob, ChannelBinding channelbinding, ExtendedProtectionPolicy
>   protectionPolicy)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.GetNextOutgoingMessageBody(Message
>   incomingMessage, SspiNegotiationTokenProviderState sspiState)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.GetNextOutgoingMessage(Message
>   incomingMessage, T negotiationState)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.DoNegotiation(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

There is no firewall between the boxes. Also, when IIS on the web server is using LocalService identity then communication between the applications works fine.

What may be causing the issues and how can I identify the root cause? I don't see any additional error messages in event logs which could shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

It was very hard to find the answer, but in my case I needed to register my IIS identity service account with host's ServicePrincipalName. The answer is available on this page: http://www.getshifting.com/wiki/setupn

What you need to do is:

1) run command `setspn -l domain\identity_user` where "`domain\identity_user`" is the user account under which IIS is running. When everything is setup correctly then this command must return you SPNs from the error message. In my case - after the fix - it returns:

```
HOST/SERV01
HOST/SERV01.DOMAIN.LOCAL
```

2) if the list is empty then you need to add those SPNs. Run:

```
setspn -A HOST/SERV01 domain\identity_user
setspn -A HOST/SERV01.DOMAIN.LOCAL domain\identity_user
```

That was it.